# is there a way to add multiple columns together if there the variable for a specific column is the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can possibly group variables together. for example, I want to average all of candy1, where the data column ~COUNTRY is 'United States' or 'Canada' or 'United Kingdom'. while removing/omitting all rows that include NA(null?)

note: what I'm trying to do for the data frame has over 2000 rows and 140 columns.

Have considered using a for loop but haven't been able to figure out how to properly do it.

```
Candy_Hierarchy <- tribble(~COUNTRY, ~candy1, ~candy2, ~candy3,
              'United States',2, 0, 1,
              'United States', 1, 2, 0,
              'United States',2, 1, 2,
              'Canada', NA, NA, NA, 
              'Canada', 2, 0, 1,
              'United Kingdom', 1, 2, 0)
```

into

```
Candy_Hierarchy <- tribble(~COUNTRY, ~candy1, ~candy2, ~candy3,
              'US, Canada, and UK', 1.6, 1, 0.8, 
              'United States',1.67, 1, 1,
              'Canada', 2, 0, 1,
              'United Kingdom', 1, 2, 0)
```

## 'US, Canada, and UK' represents the total average of 'United States', 'Canada', and 'United Kingdom averaged as a whole.

don't really have any error messages as I haven't been able to figure out a way to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

One solution: change the data from "wide" to "long" format using `tidyr::gather`, to create one column for variable name and one for values. Then you can `dplyr::group_by` COUNTRY and variable name, `dplyr::summarise` to get the mean, and `tidyr::spread` to convert back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tribble(~COUNTRY, ~candy1, ~candy2, ~candy3,
              'United States',2, 0, 1,
              'United States', 1, 2, 0,
              'United States',2, 1, 2,
              'Canada', NA, NA, NA, 
              'Canada', 2, 0, 1,
              'United Kingdom', 1, 2, 0) %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -COUNTRY) %>% 
  group_by(COUNTRY, Var) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  spread(Var, Mean)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   COUNTRY [3]
  COUNTRY        candy1 candy2 candy3
  <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Canada           2         0      1
2 United Kingdom   1         2      0
3 United States    1.67      1      1
```

Comment: Why gather and spread? Couldn't you just summarise_at or summarise_all? Something like `Candy_Hierarchy %>% group_by(COUNTRY) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean), na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Good solution. But notice that the OP wants to keep rows with all `NA`.

Comment: oh shoot sorry for the confusion, I must of accidentally not deleted that. I actually want to remove all rows with NA. Sorry for the confusion! I have fixed the post so that it shows that i do not want NA in it.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes I'm sure that would work too.

Comment: @FelixChan, In that case, it becomes very easy. Because you don't have to take care of rows with all `NA` first. I will update my post for this.

Comment: @www  Hi there currently in my data frame, my COUNTRY column contains 5 rows: NA, "0" , "Canada", "United States", "United Kingdom". if i wanted to remove the NA and "0" row how would I go to do that? Im terribly sorry for all the questions. I am very new to R and got thrown into doing a project with incredibly terrible data.

Comment: @FelixChan You can do `Candy_Hierarchy %>% filter(!is.na(COUNTRY) & COUNTRY != "0")` first.

Comment: would that be a separate line of code? so it would look like this? 
Candy_Hierarchy %>% group_by(COUNTRY) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean), na.rm=TRUE)
Candy_Hierarchy %>% filter(!is.na(COUNTRY) & COUNTRY != "0")

Comment: @www Hi I just realized that I needed to create another row where it would be the total average of "Canada", "United Kingdom" and "United States" combined, do you know how i could possible achieve this? would i need to create a new row somehow?

Comment: @FelixChan I think I know how to do this but it is difficult to answer it through comments. Please post a new question with reproducible example and expected output. I can take a look.

Comment: @www will do thanks.

Comment: @www I am trying to create a new post, but it is not allowing me to do so

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this. We can use `filter_at(vars(starts_with("candy")), all_vars(is.na(.)))` to remove rows with all `NA`. After the `summarize` operation, we can use `bind_rows` to add those rows back.

```
library(tidyverse)

Candy_Hierarchy2 <- Candy_Hierarchy %>% rowid_to_column() 

Candy_allNA <- Candy_Hierarchy2 %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("candy")), all_vars(is.na(.))) 

Candy_Hierarchy3 <- Candy_Hierarchy2 %>% 
  anti_join(Candy_allNA, by = "rowid") %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("candy")), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(
    Candy_allNA %>% select(-rowid)
  ) %>%
  arrange(COUNTRY)

Candy_Hierarchy3
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# COUNTRY        candy1 candy2 candy3
#   <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Canada           2         0      1
# 2 Canada          NA        NA     NA
# 3 United Kingdom   1         2      0
# 4 United States    1.67      1      1
```

**Update**

If no need to preserve rows with all `NA`, this operation becomes very easy under the `tidyverse`.

```
Candy_Hierarchy4 <- Candy_Hierarchy %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("candy")), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()

Candy_Hierarchy4
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   COUNTRY        candy1 candy2 candy3
#   <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Canada           2         0      1
# 2 United Kingdom   1         2      0
# 3 United States    1.67      1      1
```

Comment: would it be possible to answer it here? i cant seem to create a new question. Thanks

Comment: would creating a new row involve the mutate function? I am struggling to find a way to include the total average of canada, united kingdom and united states